# I am passing a vector to a function. Program is compiling but when I am running it, it is showing segmentation fault(core dump).

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, coredump

I want to sort a text file using merge sort. I am using vector to process the text file. This program is compiling correctly but when I am running it, it is showing segmentation fault(core dumped) error. I tried many thing but all in vain. Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

```
vector<string> sV;
void merge(vector<string> & sV, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

   vector<string> sV1;
   vector<string> sV2; 

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    sV1[i] = sV[l+1];  
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    sV2[j] = sV[m + 1 + j]; 

    i = 0; 
    j = 0; 
    k = l; 
   while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
      if (sV1[i] <= sV2[j])  
       {
        sV[k] = sV1[i]; 
        i++;
       }
      else
        {
        sV[k] = sV2[j];   
        j++;
        }
    k++;
    }

   while (i < n1)
   {
    sV[k] = sV1[i];     
    i++;
    k++;
   }
   while (j < n2)
   {
    sV[k] = sV2[j];   
    j++;
    k++;
   }
 }

void mergeSort(vector<string> & sV, int l, int r)
   {
    if (l < r)
     {
      int m = l+(r-l)/2;
      mergeSort(sV, l, m);
      mergeSort(sV, m+1, r);
      merge(sV, l, m, r);
     }
   }

int main() 
  {
   string word;
   char ch, ch1;

  ifstream tin("a1.txt");
  ofstream outp("out.txt");
  if(!tin.is_open())
     cout << "Unable to open file :) \n";

  while(tin >> word)
     sV.push_back(word);

  mergeSort(sV, 0, sV.size() - 1);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sV.size(); i++) {
    outp<< sV[i] << " ";
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your program in a debugger? Where exactly does the segfault occur?

Comment: The local vectors `sV1` and `sV2` are empty. You can not index into them until you have first added some elements.

Comment: If stepping through the program takes too long, get the core dump (you might need to set "ulimit -c unlimited" and rerun the program), feed it to a debugger (in gdb, it's "gdb path/to/the/binary path/to/the/dump") and check the call stack (in gdb, it's "bt").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot just create a vector and assign a value just like an array. You need to call vector::push_back() first which will increase the size.

once that is done you can access the member using subscript []

Comment: if and only if [index] where index < vector.size()